# Website Administration Tool

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a usermanagement for my ASP.NET Web application. I Used Website administration Tool as custom forms in my application.Currently i am Setting folder based permissions to the Roles.After that when the anonymous user click on a menuitem it will redirect it to the login page. I want to change the redirecting page to another one that showing 'The user have no rights to access this Page'.
How can i redirect it?I am new in asp.net.
Any body knows please help me...Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

In the web.config set the loginUrl to your error page, which displays the message you want

```
<forms name="AuthCookie" path="/" loginUrl="noaccess.aspx">
```